# EF core - Best way to outline the relationship between the entities

Tags: c#, .net, database, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a zone entity having columns that look like as below,

```
public class Zone
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ZoneId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public RackData RackData {get; set;}
}
```

I have another entity, RackDataItem, and the structure that looks as below.

```
public class RackDataItem
{
    [Key]
    public Guid RackDataItemId { get; set; }
    public DateTime RackDataItemBillDateTimeUTC { get; set; }
    public RackData RackData{ get; set; }
}
```

Another entity RackData as well,

```
public class RackData
{
    [Key]
    public Guid RackDataId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Building")]
    public Guid BuildingId { get; set; }
    public virtual Building Building { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RackDataItem> RackDataItems { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Zone> ZoneData { get; set; }
}
```

So, I do have the below relationships that I need to consider.

> 1. One zone can have multiple RackDataItem records
> 2. One building can have multiple zone records
> 3. Here RackData table acts as a mediator between Zones and rackdataitem entities

With the above conditions, I made the above entities structure. Since I am new to this, I am unsure whether I outlined the proper relationship among those entities.

Could anyone please let me know whether those entity relations are properly outlined or not?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Best way of do this is here :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: @RichardVíquezPérez, Thank you for pointing this out. I got confused, and am I getting things complicated with the above models? And could you please help me out with the above scenarios

Comment: Could anyone please point me in the right direction with the above relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is your Database Diagram look like**
[image: This is your Database Diagram look like]

I have to add the **Building** table

> One zone can have multiple RackDataItem records

if you want **RackDataItem** to have a relation with **Zone** is weird, they both many to one with **RackData**. In your *Models* they share no key but **it is possible to manage many *Zone* via *RackDataId* in the *RackDataItems* table**

> One building can have multiple zone records

Not necessary, one Building can have many RackData, one RackData can have many Zone, one RackData also can have many RackDataItem

```
    Here RackData table acts as a mediator between Zones and rackdataitem entities
```

So the Building is the highest Hierarchy

Comment: Sorry, I can't upvote. Will need at least 15 rep for that

Comment: No worries, it take time, it took me year for those rep :)